# left join sorting with NULL values

Tags: mysql

i need to sort left join by company id so that categories selected by companies will appear first.

My category table is

[image]

company_category table is

[image]

expected result should be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing below query is best solution rather than using union to show company categories on top.

```
SELECT * FROM category c
LEFT JOIN company_category cc ON c.category_id=cc.category_id AND cc.company_id=1
ORDER BY cc.company_id DESC
```